# Laravel -disable connections to Redis- don't need anymore

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was playing around with Redis in laravel 5 and I wanted to migrate my database to a Redis cache. I found out that Redis databasing is not supported in laravel so I switched to MySQL. I updated my .env file, my hosts Boxfile, the database connection file as well as the cache and session files and my app is still trying to connect to the server (which I got rid of). now when I run my application Laravel tries to connect to my Redis database server no matter what I do. I even cleared the applications cache. Thanks in advance for the help.

cache.php

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default cache connection that gets used while
    | using this caching library. This connection is used when another is
    | not explicitly specified when executing a given caching function.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Stores
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
    | well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
    | same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
    |
    */

    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Key Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
    | be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
    | value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => 'laravel',

];
```

session.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

];
```

database.php

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '//removede'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '//removed'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'gopagoda'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '//removed'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '//removed'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],





    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [


        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '192.168.0.3'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

.env
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:oHPYI6XIKowuqfhZaLhWayKSc5bw1XlnvFKIwWZAieI=
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    APP_URL=http://localhost

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=gopagoda
DB_USERNAME={removed}
DB_PASSWORD={removed}

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=192.168.0.3
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

Comment: Have you added DB_HOST in your .env?

Answer (score 1):

Change these values in your `.env` file to `file` to stop Laravel from using Redis.

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your database host in your .env file

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

And then run a `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve the problem. i removed the host from the post for security reasons. I also ran php artisan config;clear earlier and that did nothing.

Comment: I decided to add an unused Redis server back to my App and it worked. What are you going to do..

Comment: @TomMorison How did you do that ?