# How to disable Redis in Laravel for dev version

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, environment-variables, config

I have a Laravel API that I need to test locally. How can I disable Redis cache on a local Laravel server? I can't disable it manually deleting all `Redis::connection` cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can change "Default Cache Store" in config/cache.php file in your project.

By default you should have this `'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),`

You have a few solutions depending on what you have there:

- if you already have changed default cache driver on that file, just change it to 'file' (not recommended!)
- better would be change to default value `'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),` but add appropriate value in .env file `CACHE_DRIVER=file`

Comment: I had to set the SESSION_DRIVER to file in the .env file as well, to fully disable calls to Redis. Thanks to the post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68292038/2386108